# Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelectorAll' (sp.core.debug.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, sharepoint, cross-browser

First of all I want to tell I am new in SharePoint. I have developed a public website in SharePoint 2013. When I open my site in IE 7, following exceptions occurs in sp.core.debug.js

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelectorAll'
Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelector'
```

and sp.core.debug.js is a framework file which is located in _layouts/15/ 
any solution how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
 {(function () {
    if (document.querySelectorAll || document.querySelector) {
        return;
    }
    var
        style = document.createStyleSheet(),
        select = function (selector, maxCount) {
            var
                all = document.all,
                l = all.length,
                i,
                resultSet = [];

            style.addRule(selector, "*[id*='ElementId']");
            for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                if (all[i].id === "ElementId") {
                    resultSet.push(all[i]);
                    if (resultSet.length > maxCount) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            style.removeRule(0);
            return resultSet;
        };

    document.querySelectorAll = function (selector) {
        return select(selector, Infinity);
    };
    document.querySelector = function (selector) {
        return select(selector, 1)[0] || null;
    };
}());}
```

The above code is working fine but it is not calling object disphtmldivelement, how to call QuerySelector and QuerySelectorAll method on object disphtmldivelement.

Comment: You are supporting [IE7](http://www.theie7countdown.com/)?

Comment: yes we are supporting IE7 but this problem is not resolved yet. can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 7 is simply not supported by the Sharepoint code.

See: [Plan browser support in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx)

You might be able to use a [IE7 querySelector polyfill](https://gist.github.com/chrisjlee/8960575) and [IE7 querySelectorAll polyfill](https://gist.github.com/connrs/2724353) to support IE 7.

Comment: Dear can you please explain how to use? one answer is in my mind just download querySelector.polyfill.js and add it to my masterpage?

Comment: @Billi: Yes, you would put the polyfills in a file and load it before the code in `sp.core.debug.js` runs.

Comment: sp.core.debug.js I am not including this file. so unable to find from where it is loading and where I should add polyfills

Comment: @Billi: Then just add them as early as you can. The page content has to be loaded before the methods are used anyway, so as long as you load the polyfills in the head, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 do not support querySelectorAll. It is not defined so you will have to check it and define it on your own in javascript code. You can do it like this.

```
{(function () {
    if (document.querySelectorAll || document.querySelector) {
        return;
    }
    var
        style = document.createStyleSheet(),
        select = function (selector, maxCount) {
            var
                all = document.all,
                l = all.length,
                i,
                resultSet = [];

            style.addRule(selector, "*[id*='ElementId']");
            for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                if (all[i].id === "ElementId") {
                    resultSet.push(all[i]);
                    if (resultSet.length > maxCount) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            style.removeRule(0);
            return resultSet;
        };

    document.querySelectorAll = function (selector) {
        return select(selector, Infinity);
    };
    document.querySelector = function (selector) {
        return select(selector, 1)[0] || null;
    };
}());}
```